# How to add binding attributes dynamically in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I need the ability to add a new attribute to a given element which binds to a particular property on the view model using Aurelia. I'm guessing there's some sort of digest cycle that needs to be refreshed?

The end result is extending the Aurelua material md-input control. I need to tack on a focus attribute when declaring the control, which from a quick glance, didn't appear as though it's currently implemented.

I know Aurelia has a focus attribute but it would have to be on the input element itself.

So by placing the attribute on the control declaration, it needs to somehow be propagated down to the input control.

Any ideas?

Thanks all

Comment: are you looking for something like `<div my-attribute="foo: literal value; bar.bind: an.expression"></div>` ?

Comment: I used to compose element for what Im doing. Works out great. Thank you.